# display foreign key in javafx TableView

Tags: java, hibernate, javafx, foreign-keys, tableview

The names are in french

...................

Enseignant = Teacher

Matiere = Subject

nom = lastName

prenom = firstName

..............

i use javafx 2 with FXML and hibernate using MVC pattern,
i want to display the list of "Enseignant" in TableView

The tableView structure :

```
<TableView fx:id="tableau" >
    <columns>
        <TableColumn fx:id="ID" prefWidth="43.0" text="ID" />
        <TableColumn fx:id="NOM" prefWidth="95.0" text="NOM" />
        <TableColumn fx:id="PRENOM" prefWidth="94.0" text="PRENOM" />
        <TableColumn fx:id="MATIERE" prefWidth="97.0" text="Matière" />
    </columns>     
  </TableView>
```

in database i have 2 Tables :

```
Enseignant(ID, #idMatiere, nom, prenom)
Matiere(IDMatiere, intitule)
```

---

each table will be used by hibernate as class

Enseignant:

```
public class Enseignant  implements java.io.Serializable {

   private Integer idEnseignant;
   private Matiere matiere;
   private String nom;
   private String prenom;
```

Matiere:

```
public class Matiere  implements java.io.Serializable {


   private int idMatiere;
   private String intitule;
```

the controller of "Enseignant" has a method "show()" it displays the teachers list

```
ID.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Enseignant, Integer>("idEnseignant"));
NOM.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Enseignant, String>("nom"));
PRENOM.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Enseignant, String>("prenom"));
MATIERE.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Enseignant, String>("matiere"));
tableau.setItems(em.getEnseignant());
```

at the end, it shows me the list normal, but the "matiere" column is refering to object for example : hibernate.Matiere@59456543

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you have to change

```
MATIERE.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Enseignant, String>("matiere"));
```

to

```
MATIERE.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<Enseignant,String>,ObservableValue<String>>(){

                @Override
                public ObservableValue<String> call(CellDataFeatures<Enseignant, String> param) {
                    return new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue().getMatiere().getIntitule());
                }
            });
```

Comment: Happy to help you. :)